# Index out of range error in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

My macro throws an "index out of range" error as it goes through ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeRange on one particular group of shapes only.

The specific presentation can be found at http://free-editable-worldmap-for-powerpoint.en.softonic.com (select any larger group of shapes, i.e. South America, and run the code to replicate error)

The code is below:

```
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeRange
    shp.Fill.Transparency = 0 'Or any other code
Next shp
```

I also tried using For loop with no success ('For i=1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeRange.Count Step 1'). Notably, there is no particular index at which the error is thrown- sometimes it's i=3, sometimes i=35, sometimes more.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not able to replicate that error, and practically speaking, a `For Each` iteration should *always* circumvent an `index out of range` error. **Which particular group of shapes is causing the problem**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some `msoLine` shapes in this slide (`shp.Type = 9`).  This will raise an error:

> The specified value is out of range.

If you have inadvertently selected them.  (*I would expect an `Object does not support this property or method` error, since the msoLine does not have a `.Fill` member -- but sometimes the error messages are cryptic. In any case, this error can be trapped*).

All of the other shapes on that slide are type 5 or 6, which support the `.Fill`.

I used this to debug, although I am unable to replicate your specific error (unless you simply mistyped the error description), perhaps it will be of some assistance to you.  It attempts to set the `Fill.Forecolor` for **all** shapes in the slide, and will print some information about errors to the Immediate Window in the VBE.

```
Sub Test()
'Determine there are shapes which do not have a .Fill.ForeColor
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    On Error Resume Next
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 43506
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Description & " >> " & _
            shp.Name & " is shape type " & shp.Type
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else:
        shp.Fill.Transparency = 0
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 12632256
    End If
Next

End Sub
```